# "Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file" for Chrome while using `apt-get update`

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to use

```
sudo apt-get update
```

But i am getting error as,

```
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I tired the solution given in https://askubuntu.com/questions/120621/how-to-fix-duplicate-sources-list-entry, but again showing the same error. Suggest me something.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It looks like Google has discontinued support for i386, which is why this error now shows up. It looks like they have not gracefully for how their deb install has configured apt. To fix this run the following.

```
sudo sed -i -e 's/deb http/deb [arch=amd64] http/' "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list"
```

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/48oje6/linux_how_to_fix_failed_to_fetch/

Edit: As has been pointed out by others, another command is needed to prevent this fix from reverting. Since this is at the top as the accepted answer I feel it should be part of this answer.

```
sudo sed -i -e 's/deb http/deb [arch=amd64] http/' "/opt/google/chrome/cron/google-chrome"
```

Comment: ...thank you very much... that problem got solved now. Actually in my OS there was no file named "google-chrome.list "but there was a file named "google.list "
. So simply i changed the filename in the command you gave. Now its working fine. <br/> <pre><code> sudo sed -i -e 's/deb http/deb [arch=amd64] http/' "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list" </code></pre>

Comment: @krocks, which OS are you using?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 14.04LTS

Comment: This solution only works for maximum 24 hours. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/35850155/260805.

Comment: This answer should also address how to make `chrome` avoid automatically reverse this flag, a la the other two answers.

Answer (score 6):

Also, this issue may exist if there are two files with name **google.list** and **google-chrome.list** in **/etc/apt/sources.list.d** directory with the similar entry like:

**In google.list:**

```
  deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

**In google-chrome.list:**

```
  deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

Then you should remove google.list file or uncomment its entry like below:

```
  #deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

Comment: This is what worked for me. Thanks! 
Also, you probably mean "comment its entry" instead of "uncomment its entry"?

Comment: Thanks man, this worked.. ( dependencies should be checked while debugging.. :) )

Comment: @heykarthikwithu If it works then a upvote is appreciable. So that, other can find it helpful as well.

Answer (score 4):

That change was reverting overnight for me. Apparently you *also* need to change `/opt/google/chrome/cron/google-chrome`

```
sudo sed -i -e 's/deb http/deb [arch=amd64] http/' "/opt/google/chrome/cron/google-chrome"
```

Note: this is only for 64-bit

Source: further down that same Reddit thread and http://www.webupd8.org/2016/03/fix-failed-to-fetch-google-chrome_3.html

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/a/35850155/260805 is the more correct ang long-term solution.

Comment: @Ztyx that's hardly a good reason to vote down this accurate--if more concise--answer.

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't work because there is a default config in `/etc/default/google-chrome` that contains instructions on repository updating. If you open the google-chrome.list file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` you will see that it has the comment:

```
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
```

Like the note says, the changes using the instructions in the previous comments will probably be overwritten the next time you update. To resolve this, do the following:

1. Open a terminal and run `cd /etc/default` , then `sudo nano google-chrome` (Note: you can use whatever editor you wish of course))
2. In the config file, change the 2nd line: `repo_reenable_on_distupgrade="true"` so that it is false, as in
   `repo_reenable_on_distupgrade="false"`, then save the config file.
3. Now, you can make the edit to the repo as instructed above. In a terminal window run the commands as shown in the previous comments:

   `sudo sed -i -e 's/deb http/deb [arch=amd64] http/' "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list"`

   `sudo sed -i -e 's/deb http/deb [arch=amd64] http/' "/opt/google/chrome/cron/google-chrome"`

You changes now won't be overwritten by the config directive.

PS. This works in Linux Mint 17.3 so it will probably work in Ubuntu and any Ubuntu based distro as well.

Comment: Can you please explain, once the `cron` job file also contains the `[arch=amd64]` flag, why one needs to change `repo_reenable_on_distupgrade` to `false`? Wouldn't it now be configured correctly whenever the `list` file gets automatically updated?

Answer (score 4):

Go to "Software Sources" section in Ubuntu Settings then click on "other software" tab then uncheck: http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/stable

Now sudo apt-get update will work.

After updating manager go and undo the changes in software sources.

Comment: In my system, it was under the "Additional repositories" section.

Comment: In Ubuntu 15.04 this is under Software & updates -> other Software

Answer (score 0):

**I solved this problem by following process:**

> 1.Open a new Terminal window and run the following command:

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
```

> 2.In the text file that opens edit the file so that the line reads:

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

N.B: The only addition you need to make is entering the [amd64] architecture after ‘deb’ but preceding the ‘http’. Do not edit or replace any other text in this file.

> 3.Hit Save. Close the Gedit window and return to the Terminal and refresh your package list by runnin

```
sudo apt-get update
```

The ‘failed to fetch’ APT error should no longer appear.

source [link](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/03/fix-failed-to-fetch-google-chrome-apt-error-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

This didn't work for me, until I modified yet another file:

> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list

and changed:

> deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main

to

> deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main